# Simplifying nested if in swift

Tags: swift

My app has a class called MyDevice that I use to communicate with hardware. This hardware is optionnal, so is the instance variable:

```
var theDevice:MyDevice = nil
```

Then, in the app, I have to initialize the device (for communication) then perform a self test to check its availability and readiness to perform. If this fails, the device is either not available / reachable / is malfunctionning.

Here is my overly complicated code. I am looking how to simplify it.

```
if let device = self.theDevice
{
    device.initDevice()

    if (!device.selfTest())
    {
        self.theDevice = nil;
    }
}
```

I tried to combine all tests with && in the if statement, but it fails.
The issue is that I have 12 of them for various devices at the beginning of a function. It takes a lot of space and is dirty. How can I combine these statements in Swift ?

Comment: "combine all three test" I only see 2 `if`s. What's the third condition? Also, it doesn't seem that "overly complicated" to me. I find it very readable.

Comment: A protocol and a func you call and pass each device, and the devices could be in an array you iterate

Comment: @Arc676: thank you. I changed the text. WHat I meant is that I have to call initDevice() before selfTest().

Comment: @Wain: Thank you. Thought it looks like an array could be the solution from the example... in my case it really isn't.

Comment: Why can't you put the devices into an array?

Comment: @Arc676 Because each device is different and has to perform certain orperations. So I have a named variable for each of them. This makes for an easy-to-understand / easy-to-maintain code. And while I could put everything into an array and design a protocol just for the sake of initialization, it is just not worth the effort (much more lines). It's like putting all the Ints of a function into an array... named variables are more readable.

Comment: Nobody ever said _only_ use the array. You can create a temporary array just to reduce the number of lines of code when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` optional chaining, and combine `if case let` pattern matching and `where` statement

```
theDevice?.initDevice()
if case let selfTest? = theDevice?.selfTest() where !selfTest{
    theDevice = nil
}
```

---

But I would prefer `if let` optional unwrapping for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve this by making `initDevice` return `self`, then you could do the following:

```
if case let selfTest? = theDevice?.initDevice().selfTest() where !selfTest {
    theDevice = nil
}
```

Another option may be to make `initDevice` perform the `selfTest` and return it.

All of this assumes that the `initDevice` is your code, or you can edit in one way or another.

If it is not editable, you can always make an extension and make a new method in that:

```
extension TheDeviceClass {

    func initAndTest() -> Bool {
        initDevice()
        return selfTest()
    }
}
```

and then call it using something like this:

```
if case let selfTest? = theDevice?.initAndTest() where !selfTest {
    theDevice = nil
}
```

But this might make it more complicated than you would want. If you use this code a lot, consider putting it in another method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your MyDevice implementation to make your code less redundant, by defining a **failable initializer** and do all the checks inside it. Thus if the initialization fails you will get a nil and can just assign it to the relevant property of the other class, and don't even need the method that checks the 12 devices.

```
class MyDevice {
  func selfTest() -> Bool {
    // test
    return testresult
  }

  func initDevice() {
    // initialization
  }

  init?() {
    self.initDevice()
    if !self.selfTest() {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't like to change your code too much, you may just define a closure to reduce these redundant code, like this (**it still looks ugly so I DO NOT recommend you to do this.**):

```
class SomeClassThatHasTwelveDevices {
  var theDeviceOne: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceTwo: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceThree: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceFour: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceFive: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceSix: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceSeven: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceEight: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceNine: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceTen: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceEleven: MyDevice?
  var theDeviceTwelve: MyDevice?

  func someMethodThatChecksAllDevices() {
    let check: (inout MyDevice?) -> Void = { deviceRef in
      if let device = deviceRef {
        device.initDevice()
        if !device.selfTest() {
          deviceRef = nil
        }
      }
    }
    check(&theDeviceOne)
    check(&theDeviceTwo)
    check(&theDeviceThree)
    check(&theDeviceFour)
    check(&theDeviceFive)
    check(&theDeviceSix)
    check(&theDeviceSeven)
    check(&theDeviceEight)
    check(&theDeviceNine)
    check(&theDeviceTen)
    check(&theDeviceEleven)
    check(&theDeviceTwelve)
  }
}
```